# Retrieving the row ID PHP to add to cart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to add items to the basket but to do so I need to retrieve the row id which isn't happening at the moment.

Here's what I have so far for my table with the href:

```
<div class="row col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 custyle">
    <div id="response"></div>
     <div id="cat0"><h2>Starters</h2></div>
<table class="table table-striped custab" id="menu-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th class="text-center">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
        <tdata>
<?php
// output data of each row

foreach ($starters as $row) { ?>
            <tr><td style="width:30%;"><b><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></b></td>
            <td style="width:40%;"><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
           <td style="text-align: center">£<?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
            <td class="text-center"> <a href="customerHome.php?id=<?php echo $row['productid'] ?>" id="basketButton" value="Add To Basket"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> </a></td></tr>
               <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $row['productid'] ?>" />
                <?php
}
?>
</tdata>

</table>
</div>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

   $(document).on('click', '#basketButton', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();


    var pid = $(this).closest("tr").find(".nr").text(); // get id of clicked row


   $.ajax({
      url: 'basket.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'id='+pid,
      dataType: 'html'
   })
   .done(function(data){
      console.log(data); 

   })


  });
}); 

    </script>
```

And this is the php code for the $starters variable:

```
function getProductsCat($category){
  include('database.php');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = :category";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->bindParam(':category', $category);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  return $result;
 }
```

Can't seem to retrieve the row id, can anyone see where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: When you are creating the hyperlink for each product, you're assigning an ID to the button. If you have more than one item, this will be a duplicate ID, and the `onlick` for `#basketButton` won't know which element you're referencing. This is probably why your ID is coming through incorrectly. You may want to build the ID in a loop, and then use another loop in the JavaScript.

Comment: The starters code has been added... the id for the href is in the loop :/ - I'm a tad confused with what you mean by that.

Comment: I'm assuming you have multiple buttons. In your `foreach ($starters as $row)`, you're setting the ID as `#basketButton` for **every** element. That's invalid syntax, and may be confusing your JavaScript. You may want to use a class (`class="basketButton"`), and update the JavaScript to match: `.on('click', '.basketButton',` :)

Comment: I tried what you said, and it didn't work :/ still no ID is being passed